# How to use width relative from height?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make 3:4 window, where 3 is 75% of screen. How could i set width? Like if i have 100px height and 10000000000000px width monitor, than i shold have 75:100px window.

I heard that it could be done with the help of Javascript.

Comment: Please don't confuse [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) with [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). It's like carpet to car. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Even more importantly: do not resize my window. Ever ever ever. Don't you dare think that you know better than I do how big my window for your app should be. Make your layout flexible so that it looks decent at any size, rather than entirely disrupt my browsing experience. I will immediately leave your website if you do.

Comment: Haha, come on! Its a JQuery window on the very top of your page!

Comment: ...ahh, so it's not *really* a window. Okay. So what you're having trouble with here is the calculation of the numbers in Javascript (note: jQuery is a library, Javascript is the language), not the actual making the window itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

75*(4/3) //or any other ratio

width * (reversed ratio)

```
function getWidth(height, ratioInPercentage)
{
    return height*(ratioInPercentage/100);
}
```

use:

```
width = getWidth(100,75);
```

Comment: And where should i write this?

Comment: It's not exactly a full code sample. It just says "multiply width by the ratio."

Comment: Which is pretty much what the OP asked for.  Given more details, a more complete solution could be provided.

Comment: Question being about calculation, not implementation wasn't clear to me - downvote removed.

Answer (score 0):

window.resizeTo function will allow you to resize the window.
IE supports this if your page is the only tab in the window.
Chrome doesn't support this.

You can use screen.width and screen.height to get the screen dimension

Comment: note: screen.width and .height refer to the whole screen, not to the browser window. You may actually want window.innerWidth and .innerHeight . (I'm aware that the OP asked for screen dimensions, but that's not a very useful measurement)

Comment: note: window.innerWidth isn't supported by all browsers, which makes this living hell.  You'll have to write browser-specific JS.