# Width depends of height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can u show me completed html code where it is some rectangle in it with "height=75% of my screen" and "widtht=4/3 of height". So, it should be 3:4 reсtangle where height depends of my screenheight, but width do not depends of my screenwidth. Only of screenheight.

i thought i understood previus time, but it was not so.

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
    });
</script>
```

And i dont know what to do with the width.

Comment: [You've asked similar question before?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631972/how-to-use-width-relative-from-height) If you lost the question and answers somehow, you can find them back in your profile page which you can access by clicking anywhere where your name appears as a link like [TRAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/users/315765/trava), such as in the topbar :)

Comment: i thought i understood, but it is not so(

Comment: Hello! "Give me teh complete codez" is unlikely to get you any meaningful response, this is a "give me a hint" site, not "do my work for me" site.

Comment: Sorry. Give me hint, what to wright instead "width=" to have a result?

$(document).ready(function(){ $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true}); });

Comment: @TRAVA: I'd say something like `width:screen.height,height:screen.height*0.75`.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding your code to the question, as it makes the problem clearer. Feel free to revert if you don't like the edit.

Comment: window.innerHeight - thats what i wanted. Anyway, thanks, man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need JavaScript for computing the width, it's not possible to do this only with HTML.

The relevant property is `window.innerHeight`; multiply that by (3/4) to get height, and since (3/4)*(4/3) == 1, window.innerHeight is (incidentally) equal to your desired width.

Then set the element's `.height` and `.width` properties.

Note: I'm assuming that you wish to have a rectangle proportional to the browser window, not the user's screen. If you actually want the screen size, use `window.screen.height` instead of `window.innerHeight`; beware though: with widescreens and multi-monitor configurations on the rise, the browser may report quite outlandish dimensions.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true}); });

I'm putting "width=window.innerHeight" and it is not works.

Comment: @TRAVA: You're supposed to pass an Object - using {width:window.innerHeight,height: window.innerHeight*0.75} *might* work. Looks like you're using `=` instead of `:` there.

Answer (score 1):

HTML doesn't dictate this. CSS can, but CSS doesn't have any direct internal math logic. So, what you need to do is use javascript.

When the page loads, grab the width of the object, do your math, and then set the height.

If you're new to JS, I'd suggest learning one of the libraries, such as jQuery. In jQuery, it'd look something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').width($(this).height()*.75);
```

Comment: Yeah, i know that. Can u help me and post that completed script?

Comment: @TRAVA: you seem to be asking this: "I have all the pieces and the instructions, can you put them together for me?" It's not likely that someone will do that; can you try it yourself and report the specific problems you encountered?

Comment: I have this:  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
    
});
</script>

And i dont know what to do with the width.

Comment: @Trava, look at what I wrote and compare it to what you have.